# Moving div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have this layout:

```
<div class='layout_theme'>
  <a class='icon'>
    <img class='example_one'>
</div>

<div class=layout_theme>
  <a class='icon'>
    <img class='example_two'>
</div>

<div class='file_uploader'>
  <sample code...>
</div>
```

The idea is when I click the img 'example_one', the '.file_uploader' div moves right under it. This same idea would apply if I had 10 divs with the class 'layout_theme'. Essentially, you click an img in that div and the file upload pops up right under it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: It is possible and very simple :) I will make some example shortly :)

Comment: thanks all. i've tried messing around with jquery animate and setting top to the value of the target div, but was making it way too complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".layout_theme").click(function(){

    $(".file_uploader").animate({
        left: $(this).offset().left - parseInt($(this).css("margin-left")) + "px",
        top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() - parseInt($(this).css("margin-top")) + "px"
    }) 
});
```

Check it your here: http://jsfiddle.net/zd78e8a3/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple approach http://jsfiddle.net/xuatted6/

```
    $('.layout_theme').on('click', function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $('.file_uploader').animate({top: offset.top + 20}, 500, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

You can play with effects :)

Comment: thanks bojan! you and caeth provided exactly what i was hoping for. i appreciate it.